# Java script for loop printing with jquery function problem

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code:

```
var i;
for (i=1 ; i <= 4; i++) {

    var value = "value" + i + " "; 


$(document).ready(function(){

    document.write(value);

});

}
```

**Output:**

`value4 value4 value4 value4`

Every loop different value string will be generated and in jQuery function  should be printed. For some reason it is always printing the same value. I am using similar code structure to process api requests and it is doing exact same thing.

**What I want:**

```
value1 value2 value3 value4
```

Am I doing this wrong or is this not possible to do this way?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uygkx4os/)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/2xtqfwj5/1/

Comment: Remove the document ready event handler and put it at the top level of the code. The document only gets ready once.

Comment: It is also weird you would have multiple document.ready calls.